# Graph of $x=1$ in space

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to graph $x=1$ in space... this is my first idea...

[image: Taller No. 2 - 2 - x equals 1 in space]

It is a plane parallel to the $yz$ plane.

Is it correct?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Comment: Correct, it's the set of points $\left\{(1,y,z)|y,z\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$! ;)

Comment: By in space, you mean in 3 dimensions.